# How to upgrade a MySQL database using numbered scripts based on a version field

Tags: mysql, upgrade, scripting, automation

I have a database that contains a version table with one value stored in it which is the database version number.

I would like to be able to update the database version automatically using numbered scripts.

If the database is version "6" and I have a dir of scrips numbered inconsistently as per the below:

```
001.sql, 02.sql, 3.sql, 4script.sql, 5.sql, 6.upgrade.sql, 7.sql, 8.data.sql, 009.updated.sql
```

What is the best way to only run scripts which are numbered greater than the version number and to do this in sequence?

Should I use an SQL script or create a bash script?

I am a little stuck on how to approach this so any pointers or advice will be much appreciated...

Comment: Well, I'd start by renaming the files for consistency - you're asking for trouble otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Create "main script" which detects current DB version and shells only scripts proper for it. For example, it can look like

```
drop procedure if exists main_proc;
delimiter @@;
create procedure main_proc
    select version into @version from service_table;
    if @version < 2 then 
        source 001.sql;
        update service_table set version = 2;
    end if;
    if @version < 2.5 then 
        source 02.sql;
        update service_table set version = 2.5;
    end if;
    if @version < 3 then 
        source 3.sql;
        update service_table set version = 3;
    end if;
    -- and so on
    end; 
@@;
delimiter ;
call main_proc;
drop procedure main_proc;
```

Don't forget error handlers (no script file or access error, error during script execution, etc.).